# Reducing Ruby on Rails traffic to the database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, scalability

The networking team has flagged our Ruby on Rails application as one of the top producers of network traffic on our network, specifically from packet traffic between the app server and the database server (mysql).

What are the recommended best practices to reduce traffic between a Rails app and the database?  Persistent database connections?

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but the #1 thing to do is probably reducing the number of queries - either by, reducing their number, or caching. If the actual traffic is the problem, persistent connections aren't going to help much

Answer (score 2):

Is it an actual problem, or do they ding the top 3 db consumers no matter what? Check your logs or have them supply you with a log of queries that they think are problematic.

Beyond that, check to see if you're doing bad things like making model calls from your views in loops. Your logs should tell you what's going on here, if you see each partial paired with a query every time it's rendered, that's a big sign that your logic should be pulled back into the models and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up Wireshark or another network scanner and look for the biggest packets or small packets that are too frequent - to identify the specific, troublesome queries.

Then, before even considering caching, check if that query can really be cached or if it just pulls too much data you are not using.

At this point, there are too many different possible causes - each with it's own recommended practices.